# Layout Galaxy S2 and HTC Sensation

Tags: android, layout, screen

Do I see the same layout on Galaxy S2 and HTC Sensation.

I think they are both normal-large or large-hdpi, but have a different density and therefore the layout is not identical.

It 'just that they have a different density? And how do I manage this thing?

Comment: Can you post the layout xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Because the devices have different screens (size, pixel density, resolution), it will always look different on the devices. Unless you specify a layout for each different screen, the layout you defined will be scaled approprietly to the screen. This often comes out almost the same, IF you have used mostly 'density independent pixels'(dip) for the measurements.

EDIT
In the onCreate method in your activity you could first obtain the devices name by using

```
 android.os.Build //read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL
```

and then use setContentView to set the desired layout.xml

Comment: The problem is this, how do I specify a different layout for each?

Comment: I believe that taking the Model of the device is not a good idea. I find it better to create a layout for resolutions of 540x960. So in the onCreate method, I take the resolution and select the right layout. What do you think?